# Unable to override css property

Tags: html, css

Hi I have provided with a project which has many CSS files included. with following structure

```
<link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/jquery.owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/kumi.global.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/kumi.style.scss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/kumi.media.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
   <link href="./Premium Nutritional Supplements_files/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I have included **custom.css** at the end to override a property

```
.post-author-image{
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

in  **kumi.global.css** which is above **custom.css** and contains

```
div, input, select, textarea, span, img, table, td, th, p, a, button, ul, li {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0!important;
}
```

But I m unable to override border-radius in custom.css. How can I override border-radius from 0 to 50%?

Comment: border-radius: 50% !important;

Comment: This is why `!important` is evil.

Comment: Remove those `!important`

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify `kumi.global.css`? The correct answer here is to remove those `!important` markers. You should also hunt down the original developer of `kumi.global.css` and force him to write down 10000 times *"I will not use !important in my CSS code"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using !important should do it since custom.css loads at last.

```
.post-author-image{
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

`!important` gives css a higher priority and since "kumi" css has `!important`, no matter where you put your custom css, "kumi" css will take effect.

It is generally a bad idea to use `!important` especially when you are selecting a generic dom element which is in your case with "kumi css" where `!important` is used for almost everything.

If possible, a better solution will be to remove `!important` from "Kumi" css

Comment: When will people learn to cure the cause instead of the symptom?

Comment: @user1 it would be beneficial if you explained why it works and why it's generally considered a bad idea. It's what holding me back from going 'this guy deserves a 1 up!'

Answer (score 0):

Woah. I hope that you can change kumi.global.css, because that `!important` tag is put to *horrific* use. It almost seems like a hard-artillery approach to banning use of border-radius.

Here's the direct solution:

```
.post-author-image{
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

But I hope you're able to remove that tag from the global file.